# open a file in an emacs buffer while in emacs terminal

Tags: bash, emacs

Suppose I am in terminal in Emacs (M-x term), and I list the following files in current directory:

`text_code.R`

Now I am in bash-3.2$ (terminal) and hope to open this .R file in another Emacs buffer and then edit. Is there a way to do it? This might be a trivial question, for I am a newbie to Linux and Emacs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that in Term Mode you can type <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd> to open a file (just like <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> outside Term Mode). The prompt will already be on your current directory, so you just have to start typing the name of the file and autocomplete it with <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Comment: thanks a lot! That works and is really convenient within the bash mode :)

Comment: But, surprisingly this is shell dependent. This doesn't work in `fish-shell`

Comment: Neither for `zsh`, for `bash` it does

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the official procedure for what you want to do, but here is a procedure that works:

1. Either tell emacs to run as a daemon (Ref: [EmacsAsDaemon](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon)) or in emacs start daemon via `M-x server-start`.
2. In the term, a command like `emacsclient -n filename` will start editing the specified file in the current window.  Note, emacsclient also has a `-c, --create-frame` option to edit in a new frame.  You probably will want to use a `-n` option as above, so you can continue using your term, after selecting it from the buffers list in another pane or frame.
3. If you start the daemon via `M-x server-start` in emacs, the daemon will terminate when you exit from emacs.  If you set it up via reference mentioned above, use `kill-emacs` or `save-buffers-kill-emacs` commands or shell command `emacsclient -e '(kill-emacs)'` to stop it, as mentioned in part 6 of reference.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! It seems to be a little complicated.. what I hope to see is some key-binding in emacs that will do the work. Maybe there is none. Anyway, thanks again!